Finalizing GA4 migration - are Universal Tags going to become inactive?
We are finalizing our migration to Google Analytics 4. Our current client base has a bunch of accounts that are using Universal Analytics tags. Do I need to go through and remove those/replace all with their new GA4 tags?
Our current code:
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.analyticsCode = 'UNIVERSAL-TAG';
function gtag(){ dataLayer.push(arguments); }
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'UNIVERSAL-TAG'); //GA Property ID

gtag('config', 'UNIVERSAL-TAG', {
        // custom mapping and dimensions . . .
    }
});

// configure the GA4 tag    
gtag('config', 'GA4-TAG');

I think I need to update this to:
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.analyticsCode = 'GA4-TAG';
function gtag(){ dataLayer.push(arguments); }
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'GA4-TAG'); //GA Property ID

gtag('config', 'GA4-TAG', {
    'custom_map': {
        // custom mapping and dimensions . . .
    }
});

I want to make sure that I don't lose data recording or past data when they shut off Universal next week.

So the simplest way to migrate UA to GA4 is to go there into the UA UI and connect it to a GA4 property.
When you do that, what it does is it puts a relay in place that starts redirecting UA tracking into the GA4 property, mapping all fields to the best of its ability, maybe reimplementing UA's session logic since it's absent in GA4 natively.
That part will be up. So technically, your front-end analytics.js library will continue working in that scenario.
This migration, however, is not optimal since the router will remap the CDs into EPs as it sees fit. And probably other issues.
So yes, it's better to completely migrate from UA to GA4 before UA stops collecting data. Plus, UA has been malfunctioning more and more since Google stopped supporting it a while ago. A lot of people experience troubles accessing their data. Better export it to BQ asap if you need it.

Well, we've fully migrated as of sometime last year, we have kept a special link just to look at the historical data that will go away onn Monday. I was just wondering if the universal tags need to be replaced... sounds like the answer is yes.

And by migration you mean linking UA to GA4 accounts? Then you need to be careful updating the code like that. I believe the way gtag maps custom dimensions for GA4 is different from UA. I would recommend switching to GTM and getting rid of direct gtag calls.

Switch to GTM will have to be a longer process though. So I would take my time reimplementing everything and I would have a lower environment to test it where gtag is removed from. And while I'm doing that, the UA tags will still collect data even after the deprecation of UA. At least that's what the industry expects since that's one of the migration routes Google pushes for.
